# Free web cron service

Tags: gratis, web-apps, automation

I'm looking for a cron job web service that is:

- Reliable
- Flexible
- Free

I need to be able to schedule cron to execute.

Comment: What exactly do you need your cron job to do (http post?)? and free and reliable don't usually go together [GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) may be an answer

Comment: HTTP/GET actually) I need it to be run remotely, so GAE probably won't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Azure Scheduler](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) can do HTTP requests (GET/POST) and has a free tier. It is very reliable and can be bent in any way. Free tier is limited with number of requests, but can be worked with.

Also there is [Aditi Scheduler](https://brewmaster.aditicloud.com/Home/pricing) that has a free tier limited to 500 requests/month. I have not tried it, so can't comment on how flexible it is.

Comment: `Azure` is anything else but _reliable_, but it may work for me as I need to do HTTP requests to `Azure`.

Comment: My experience have been completely opposite. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an example of where you can't have all 3 characteristics; you can only pick 2.

Try https://uptimerobot.com/. It's not that flexible (can't schedule specific times), but you get the added benefit of being notified when something fails. If that doesn't work, you can try user2813274's suggestion of [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron).

Comment: seems like https://uptimerobot.com/ is down now (it wasn't responding to me at first and then I got `500` `ISE`, so there goes that ...

Answer (score 0):

EasyCron https://www.easycron.com provides the most stable Cron Job Services. Here you can schedule cron jobs with execution logs, Email notifications, run time predictions and a bunch of other featuers!

Comment: Website says it's only a 7 day free trial. But EasyCron is an interesting concept.

Comment: EasyCron provides a free plan at https://www.easycron.com/user/register/plan/1 that allows scheduling cron jobs run every 10 minutes.